# Xubuntu refuses to stay in suspend

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management

Starting about a week ago the suspend functionality in Xubuntu seemingly stopped working. Behavior is that after suspend is initiated, about three minutes later, suspend ends and lock screen is shown. With the exception of regular upgrades, there's nothing new on my system and even if there was, it shouldn't interfere with suspend.

Looks like a similar issue effected this user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058672/ubuntu-22-04-1-wake-up-immediatly-after-suspend

Xfce version 4.14. Ubuntu 20.04.6.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.